# I seem to have accidentally made a fork bomb of some sort in nodejs, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, livereload

Below is my code for the /search page on my local webserver. I want to be able to update the page, and display the most recent search query. the problem is that by reloading the page, I end up running the portion that writes to a file (which inadvertently reloads the page) etc etc etc. Leading a vicious cycle of writing and reloading that can quickly get out of hand. Can you help me find a way to avoid this?

```js
app.get('/search/', async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body)
    // console.log(req.body.query)
    var act = null;
    var intervalId = setInterval(async function() {
        if (req.body.query) {
            act = await searchTweets(req.body.query);
        } else {
            act = await searchTweets("CVE")
        }
        fs.writeFile("./search.html", `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>\n<a href='http://localhost:${port}/index.html' class='button'>Return to homepage</a>\n` + act + '\n</body>\n</html>', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
        })
    }, 5000);
    fs.readFile("./search.html", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        res.send(data);
        // Display the file content
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

P.S. to monitor the file for changing I am using livereload:
`liverlserver.watch("../BasicServer");`

Comment: Why do you want to use setInterval?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `setInterval`?  For every request you're starting something that's going to run every 5 seconds, for every time you make a request.

Comment: Im trying to run a function which pulls tweets every 5 seconds, then writes that data to an html file.